# Simple explanation on artificial neural networks?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I've Googled, StackOverflowed, everything, and I cannot seem to find a tutorial I can understand.  I understand the concept of genetic algorithms, and how to implement them, (Though I haven't tried) but I cannot grasp the concept of neural networks.

I know vaguely how they work... And that's about it.  Could someone give an explanation that can help someone who has not even graduated middle school yet?

Comment: Some topics are taught at advanced levels because they require a grasp of more basic topics before one can approach them properly.  I suspect that ANN should only be attacked by someone who does grasp summation and vectors.  So I'll be intrigued by any answers you get.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to look for tutorials on solving the problem that you want to solve instead of focusing specifically on neural networks.  I find that concrete examples can really make a solution strategy more clear.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  FrustratedWithFormsDesigner's answer helped me with a lot of things, so I'll probably give him a check soon.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: I believe addition and multiplication are taught at reasonably young ages these days...

To put it another way - simple feedforward networks are unbelievably trivial. There's no reason why there couldn't be a very simple tutorial for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Summation is just adding up a bunch of things. So,

```
Summation(1,2,3,4,5) = 1+2+3+4+5 = 15
```

(note: it's *always* adding: if you want to subtract, do a summation with negative numbers)

That was easy, right? ;)

A vector is an ordered tuple, which really just means it's bunch of numbers in a specific order. Most often seen in physics to describe position, force, velocity, etc... it's really nothing special, just some ordered numbers, where the ordering is significant:

```
v = <1,2,3>
```

If we are talking about geometry, then this vector represents a point in 3-dimensional space where the x coordinate is 1, the y coordinate is 2, and the z coordinate is 3 (See that was easy too, right)?

In neural nets, the vector is usually the vector of inputs to a neuron, so it's really just a list of numeric values. The summation of the vector would be nothing more than adding up all of the values in the vector and getting a single number as a result (which may be referred to as as "scalar" value).

(this was rushed and simplified - I'm sure someone else will help me refine it ;) )

PS. Kudos to you for diving into this stuff at the middle school level! :)

Comment: Okay, I'm doing fine so far in a tutorial with your help, but on this page in it, (http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt5.html) it talks about a vector containing two values *pointing* to the closest land mine.  Does that mean it's a vector containing the coordinates of the closest land mine?  And it also mentions a second vector, also containing two values, that represents the direction the minesweeper is pointing.  What are these?  Wouldn't you need only one value to represent the angle of the minesweeper, just a value in radians?  I'm confused.

Comment: Wait a second, I burrowed through the internet and I think I may have discovered that vectors are angle as well as distance.  Is this true?  If it is, then it would all make sense.

Comment: @Stuart: In this context, I think vector is being used slightly differently than what I had said. I think they are talking about two numeric values that represent a vector. This vector is sort of like a line between the minesweeper and the nearest mine, assuming that the minesweeper is at location (0,0) (it isn't but that's OK since the vector is *relative to the minesweeper's position*).

Comment: @Stuart: ...The other vector that represents which direction the minesweeper is pointing is ALSO 2 probably numeric values (x and y coordinate), and you are probably right, an angle from the x-axis *probably8 could be used instead - but they chose to use a vector. I didn't read it in too much detail so they might have had a good reason to use a vector rather than an angle. Both methods will probably work fine, and it might just be a matter of preference.

Comment: @Stuart: Basically: when I last worked with neural nets, I used the term "vector" to refer to a whole set of inputs to a neuron. In this case, "vector" is actual geomtric data that is input as seperate values into the neuron. Both uses of the word seem correct, though yes, a bit confusing. ;)
(In fact, if each input to the neuron was a whole vector rather than a scalar, you would have an input vector made up of vectors!)

Comment: @Stuart: The angle between a vector and an axis can be easily found (but a vector is NOT an angle). A vector represents a line to a point at (x,y) from the origin (at (0,0)). The length of the vector is easily calculated (and the other lengths are known), and you can use the properties of a right-angled triangle to calculate the angle between the vector and an axis.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for a while. I'm a high school student, so you're a little ahead of me. I got a vacation and I used it to learn all I could on backpropagation, and I've found almost no resources that really help too much unless you want to read so much calculus that you want to die. My advice is to first write a perceptron, which is a network with only input layers and output layers. This inspired me o write a post, so hopefully within half an hour of my posting here there should be a tutorial on http://certioraomnia.blogspot.com/. It may be a little late as this question was asked three years ago, but it may help others later.